# aff-ify a function that has different resulting types in error and success callback

Tags: purescript

Let's first look at a similar function from the web-gl package, for which the intention works:

```
withShaders
  :: forall bindings eff a
   . Shaders ({ | bindings }) -> (String -> EffWebGL eff a) -> ({ webGLProgram :: WebGLProg | bindings } -> EffWebGL eff a) -> EffWebGL eff a


makeAff
  :: forall e a
   . ((Error -> Eff e Unit) -> (a -> Eff e Unit) -> Eff e Unit) -> Aff e a


withShadersAff :: forall eff a. Shaders { | a } -> Aff ( webgl ∷ WebGl | eff ) { webGLProgram ∷ WebGLProg | a }
withShadersAff arg = makeAff (\err ok -> withShaders arg (error >>> err) ok)
```

This basically turns the callback based `withShaders` function into one that can be used in `aff` context.

I'm wondering why, the same thing does not work with the following function (also from the webgl package):

```
runWebGL :: forall a eff. String -> (String -> Eff eff a) -> (WebGLContext -> EffWebGL eff a) -> Eff eff a


runWebGLAff :: forall eff . String -> Aff ( webgl ∷ WebGl | eff ) WebGLContext
runWebGLAff arg = makeAff (\err ok -> runWebGL arg (error >>> err) ok)
```

This gives me an 'infinite type error' for the last function. I guess it's because here the error callback and the success callback don't share the same result type, but I could not find away to fix this.

---

**EDIT**

After reading the accpeted answer, the solution is:

```
runWebGLAff arg = makeAff (\err ok -> runWebGL arg (error >>> err) (unsafeCoerceEff <<< ok))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`EffWebGL` is defined as follows [in the library](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-webgl/2.0.1/docs/Control.Monad.Eff.WebGL#t:EffWebGL):

```
type EffWebGL eff a = Eff (webgl :: WebGl | eff) a
```

It's just an alias for `Eff`, but notice that its effect row includes the `WebGl` effect.

When the compiler tries to reconcile this in your function, it deduces, from the usage of `ok` as callback, that `ok :: Eff (webgl | eff) a`, but since the `ok` callback must have the same type as the error callback (from the signature of `makeAff`), the compiler also deduces that `err :: Eff (webgl | eff) a`, and therefore, `error >>> err :: Eff (webgl | eff) a`. However, since `error >>> err` is used as parameter to `runWebGL`, it means that `error >>> err :: Eff eff a` (that's how `runWebGL` is defined). So the compiler now has two pieces of information that must be true:

```
(1)  error >>> err :: Eff (webgl | eff) a
(2)  error >>> err :: Eff eff a
```

And this, of course, must mean that `(webgl | eff) === eff`. So `eff` is part of its own definition. Aka "infinite type". That's why you're getting the error.

Now, in order to fix it, you must take your parameter `err` as `Eff (webgl | eff) a` (as required by the type of `makeAff`), but pass it to `runWebGL` as `Eff eff a` (as required by the type of `runWebGL`) - i.e. the effect row would widen as it flows from the inner callback to the outer. This should be perfectly safe to do, since the inner callback would never use this effect anyway (as indicated by its type), however, the compiler doesn't have a safe way to do this - which might be one of the reasons the effect rows were ditched in PureScript 0.12 (and good riddance!)

Instead, you have to use the type-unsafe way [from `Control.Monad.Eff.Unsafe`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-eff/3.2.1/docs/Control.Monad.Eff.Unsafe#v:unsafeCoerceEff):

```
unsafeCoerceEff :: forall eff1 eff2 a. Eff eff1 a -> Eff eff2 a
```

Just wrap the error callback in a call to this function, and it will work:

```
runWebGLAff arg = makeAff (\err ok -> runWebGL arg (unsafeCoerceEff $ error >>> err) ok)
```

---

P.S. Normally I would recommend switching to PS 0.12, but it seems you can't do that, because the WebGL library hasn't been updated (yet?).

Comment: Great, thanks for the detailed information! It turned out that the compiler is only happy if the ok-callback is wrapped with `unsafeCoerceEff` instead of the error one. I'll put the final working example to the post above.. Regarding PS.12, yes - the web-gl package is not updated yet and so I have to use an older PS version + tons of old, old libraries (e.g. `aff` in 3... something)

Comment: Don't coerce the ok callback, that actually might be dangerous, because the callback is using the webgl effect, but you're hiding it from the consumer.